# How do I extract a string and put into a list WITHOUT split function?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the words from a string and assign each word to a list. Not just listing all the words. Here is what I need to do, list all the words, but I need to assign each word to a list and then print each word onto a separate line, and at the bottom of the list state the number of letters (including spaces and punctuation) and the number of words found.

```
EnterSentence = input('Please Enter A Sentence: ')
EnterSentence = str(EnterSentence)

print (' you entered:')
print (EnterSentence)
import re
res = re.findall(r'\w+', EnterSentence)
print (' the list of words is : ' + str(res))
```

Output: I was working with 'Hello my name is bot'

```
Please Enter A Sentence: hello my name is bot
you entered: hello my name is bot
the list of words is : ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'bot']
```

Comment: You've shown us an input and output, but is this the output you are actually expecting?  If not, what do you expect here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import re

EnterSentence = input('Please Enter A Sentence: ')
print ('You entered: ' + EnterSentence)

res = re.findall(r'\w+', EnterSentence)
print ('The list of words is:')
for word in res:
    print(word)

print(f"Number of letters: {len(EnterSentence)}")
print(f"Number of words: {len(res)}")
```

Comment: I was able to count the letters, but I am having trouble counting the words : EnterSentence = input('Please Enter A Sentence: ')
EnterSentence = str(EnterSentence)


import re
WordList = re.findall(r'\w+', EnterSentence)
print ('You Entered: ')
for word in WordList:
    print(word)

LetterCount = len(EnterSentence)
Letters = int(LetterCount)
print ('Letters:',(Letters))

Comment: I'd missed that part of the q because you didn't have any code for it... but you already have a list of words that you can get the length of... I'll update the answer a bit later